# Re-ordering columns with a Perl one-liner

Tags: linux, perl

How do you reorganize this with one liner

```
foo  r1.1   abc
foo  r10.1  pqr
qux  r2.1   lmn
bar  r33.1  xpq

# In fact there could be more fields that preceeds column with "rxx.x".
```

Into this

```
r1.1  foo  abc
r10.1 foo  pqr
r2.1  qux  lmn
r33.1 bar  xpq
```

Basically, put second column into the first and everything else that succeeds  it, after.

Comment: Why would it have to be a one-liner?

Comment: @JB : It doesn't have to be, but why complicate life when it can be simple?

Comment: @Zaid: my point being: a one-liner tends to be shorter, not simpler.

Comment: Crossposted to PerlMonks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=940072   In the future please let both communities know when you're putting us all in a position of duplicating work for you.  It's only polite to inform us there's someone else also working on the problem.

Comment: Can any of the column fields be empty? E.g. "\tr1.2\txyz" (first column empty).

Comment: Also, what exactly is the delimiter? Tab or space? Fixed width?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your text is in the file "test", this will do it:

```
perl  -lane 'print "$F[1] $F[0] $F[2]"' test
```

Comment: it didn't chomp the line. Is there  a way to modify you great one liner?

Comment: @neversaint it does chomp, unless you're doing something like processing a windows file on a non-windows system, in which case you can try running with `PERLIO=:unix:crlf` in environment.

Comment: `"$F[1] $F[0] $F[2]"` better written as a slice `"@F[1,0,2]"`, especially when there are more fields.

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than three columns, you will want something like:

```
perl -lane 'print join q( ),$F[1],$F[0],@F[2..@F-1]'
```

Comment: `perl -lane 'print join "$F[1] $F[0] @F[2..$#F]"'` does the same thing more simply.

Comment: @davorg : I think you meant without the 'join' and then, yes, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -pale '$_ = "@F[1,0,2..$#F]"' file
```

If it's tab-separated, a little more is needed:

```
$ perl -pale 'BEGIN { $"="\t"; } $_ = "@F[1,0,2..$#F]"' file
```

Comment: I think you meant to add the '-a' to autosplit.  Given that your solution is better/shorter than mine.

Comment: @James_R_Ferguson : I added it before you mentioned it ;)

Comment: +1 Nice outside the box version. Monkey wrench: What if you have empty fields?

Comment: @TLP : Simply change the default `\s+` delimiter to `\t` with the `-F` flag :).

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. =) Except it won't work if it's fixed width.

Comment: @TLP : Exactly. Fixed-width columns need to be handled differently.

Answer (score 2):

Content of 'infile':

```
foo  r1.1   abc
foo  r10.1  pqr
qux  r2.1   lmn
bar  r33.1  xpq
```

Perl one-line:

```
perl -pe 's/\A(\S+\s+)(\S+\s+)/$2$1/' infile
```

Result:

```
r1.1   foo  abc
r10.1  foo  pqr
r2.1   qux  lmn
r33.1  bar  xpq
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic answers are provided by others, I considered the case of fixed width data with possible empty fields:

```
>cat spacedata.txt
foo  r1.1   abc
foo  r10.1  pqr
qux  r2.1   lmn
bar  r33.1  xpq
     r1.2   cake
is   r1.2   alie

>perl -lpwE '$_=pack "A7A5A*", (unpack "A5A7A*")[1,0,2];' spacedata.txt
r1.1   foo  abc
r10.1  foo  pqr
r2.1   qux  lmn
r33.1  bar  xpq
r1.2        cake
r1.2   is   alie
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file
a 5 ss
b 3 ff
c 2 zz

cat file | awk '{print $2, $1, $3}' # will print column 2,1,3

5 a ss
3 b ff
2 c zz

#or if you want to sort by column and print to new_file

cat file | sort -n -k2 | awk '{print $0}' > new_file

new_file
c 2 zz
b 3 ff
a 5 ss
```